# What's the sequence $3,9,24,21,36,30,75,120,270,462,837,1320,2085,\ldots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, integer-partitions

In order to find a formula of the partition of an integer into 5 parts (see $(6)$ below), I find the sequence
$$S_1: 3,9,24,21,36,30,75,120,270,462,837,1320,2085,\ldots \tag1$$

It's clear that $S_1$ is divisible by $3$, so I got the sequence
$$S_2: 1,3,8,7,12,10,25,40,90,154,279,440,695,\ldots \tag2$$

I can't figure out what's this sequence. I tried to divide the sequence into two other sequences:

The odd sequence
$$S_3: 3,7,10,40,154,440,\ldots\tag3$$
and the even sequence
$$S_4: 1,8,12,25,90,279,695,\ldots\tag4$$
but yet I can't find any answer.

---

More details:

For example, the formula of the partition of an integer into 3 parts is [A069905](https://oeis.org/A069905)

$$p_3(n)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{12}n^2 &\text{if}\; n=6k \\[4pt]
\frac1{12}(n^2-1) &\text{if}\; n=6k+1 \;\text{or}\; n=6k+5 \\[4pt] 
\frac1{12}(n^2-4) &\text{if}\; n=6k+2 \;\text{or}\; n=6k+4 \\[4pt]
\frac1{12}(n^2+3) &\text{if}\; n=6k+3
\end{cases}\tag5$$

$p_3(n)$ is a mod $6$ formula. I managed to find also $p_4(n)$, and it's a mod $12$ formula, [A026810](https://oeis.org/A026810). I suspect that $p_5(n)$ is a mod $15$ formula.

While working in the case $n=15k+5$, I found
$$\begin{align}
p_5(5) &=\frac13((\phantom{9}5 \cdot\phantom{99}0)+\phantom{9}\color{red}{3})+0 &&=1 \\[4pt]
p_5(20)&=\frac13((20\cdot\phantom{9}12)+\phantom{9}\color{red}{9})+1 &&=84 \\[4pt]
p_5(35)&=\frac13((35\cdot\phantom{9}57)+\color{red}{24})+1 &&=674 \\[4pt]
p_5(50)&=\frac13((50\cdot156)+\color{red}{21})+4 &&=2611 \\[4pt]
p_5(65)&=\frac13((65\cdot330)+\color{red}{36})+4 &&=7166 \\[4pt]
p_5(80)&=\frac13((80\cdot600)+\color{red}{30})+9 &&=16019 \\[4pt]
p_5(95)&=\frac13((95\cdot987)+\color{red}{75})+9 &&=31289\\[4pt]
\cdots &= \cdots
\end{align} \tag6$$

The sequence of multipliers: $0,12,57,156,330,600,987,\ldots$ is the sequence $3a(n)$, with $a(n) = \frac16n(n + 1)(7n + 5)$.

The sequence: $0,1,1,4,4,9,9,\ldots$ is the squares sequence ($0$ for $0$).

Then the sequence $S_1$ appears highlighted in red.

Any answer please?

Comment: Where does that sequence come from?

Comment: while working in restricted partition , precisely in partition of an integer into 5 parts, i try to find a formula, i find many sequences that match together, this is the only sequence left

Comment: I suggest that you describe exactly how you came up with the sequence (in the question itself, with an [edit]).

Comment: It's not in the OEIS, so it's not a known sequence.

Comment: i edit the question , there are more details

Comment: @ayoubsabeurrguez: Did you find identifiable patterns with the *other* $15k+m$ cases? If so, please list them. They may provide insights. ... For that matter, seeing your $p_4$ formulas may be helpful, as well.

Comment: Your sequence $S_1$ should start with $3$ (not $0$) -- because $3a(0)=0$ (not $3$) -- and your list should have $p_5(95)=31289$ (not $25337$).

Comment: Try dividing it into $4$ subsequences.

Comment: (In case my hint isn't enough.... $p_5(n)$ is a mod $60$ formula, not mod $15$.  So you will only find polynomial expressions for each of the four equally spaced subsequences.)

Comment: @mjqxxxx  for pi(n)  in general you know it's mod? formula??

Comment: I don’t know for sure.  Based on the first few, I’d conjecture it’s the least common multiple of the numbers $2,3,\ldots, i$.

Answer (score 1):

The number of partitions of n into 5 parts is https://oeis.org/A026811 which has
the generating function
$$ x^5/[(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)/(1-x^4)/(1-x^5)]$$.
So the number of ways of paritions of 5n into 5 parts is 1,84,674,2611,..
and has the generating function
$$
g_1 = ( -1-81*x-424*x^2-759*x^3-845*x^4-759*x^5-424*x^6-81*x^7-x^8 ) / ( (x^2+1)*(1+x)^2*(x-1)^5 )
$$
Now the generating function of 0,1,1,4,4,9,9 (squares repeated) is
$$
g_2= -x*(1+x^2) / ( (1+x)^2*(x-1)^3 ).
$$
Subtracting both generating functions and multiplication with 3 gives the generating function for
the sequence 5*3+0, 20*12+9, 35*57+24,...
Since the generating function of 3,12,57,156,... =3,... $1/2*n*(n+1)*(7*n+5)$ is
$$3+ 3*x*(4+3*x) ) / (x-1)^4 $$
the generating function of 5*3, 20*12, 35*57, 50*156 is 15,... 1/2*n*(n+1)*(7*n+5)*(15*n+5)
$$
g_3 = 15 -15*x*(5*x+16)*(3*x+1) / ( (x-1)^5 )
$$
so the generating function for 0,9,24,21,...
is (note the mismatch for the 0th term because the $p_5(5)$ value  does not match the formula):
$$ 3(g_1-g_2)-g_3 -> -3*x*(3-x-11*x^2+13*x^3-8*x^4+13*x^5+7*x^6-2*x^7+x^8)/(x^2+1)/(1+x)^2/(x-1)^5$$
with a recurrence of the type
$$a(n)= +3*a(n-1) -2*a(n-2) -2*a(n-3) +4*a(n-4) -4*a(n-5) +2*a(n-6) +2*a(n-7) -3*a(n-8) +a(n-9)$$ for $n-9>0$.